# Can I move /opt to the / partition?

Tags: partitioning, filesystem

I have `/opt` on a separate partition. Can I move it to the `/` partition to install Windows Vista?

I currently have the following setup:

```
/     partition
/home partition
/opt  partition
swap  partition
```

Comment: What you have in `/opt`? Use the terminal and run `ls /opt` edit your question and add the results.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to, without too much fuss. The `/opt` folder usually shouldn't contain critical system programs/files anyway. You just have to remount the `/opt` partition elsewhere then copy the files into the `/opt` folder in the main partition like so:

1. Make sure nothing is using anything in the `/opt` folder. You may use the command `lsof | grep /opt` to that end.
2. Use this to find your `/opt` partition name (skip if known).

   ```
   mount -l | grep "/opt" | cut -d " " -f 1
   ```
3. Remount it elsewhere with this (substituting the correct partition identifier).

   ```
   sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/<partition> /mnt
   ```
4. Make a `/opt` folder in your system drive.

   ```
   sudo mkdir /opt
   ```
5. Copy the files from your original `/opt` partition to the new folder.

   ```
   sudo cp -Ra /mnt /opt
   ```
6. Umount the `/opt` partition.

   ```
   sudo umount /mnt
   ```
7. Check `/etc/fstab` for any references to `/opt`.

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/fstab
   ```
8. Find any lines with `/opt` in them and delete them completely.
9. Save then close the file.

References:

- [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES)

Comment: I Am New To Ubuntu but what do you mean 'remount it elsewhere?'

Comment: @user19 I've outlined steps for you to follow, just run the commands in a terminal. 'remount it elsewhere' is a simple description of what the command following will do

Comment: @user197060 Just at step 3 ('Remount it elsewhere'), make sure to replace `/dev/<partition>` with the result you got from step 2

Comment: My /opt partition is on dev/sda6 but when i try to remount it i get mount: can't find /dev/sda6/mnt in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab

Comment: @user197060, that's because you're missing a space between `/dev/sda6` and `/mnt`.  Spaces separate different _arguments_ to a command-line program.  `mount` takes the first argument - `/dev/sda6` - and tries to mount it in the location pointed to by the second argument - `/mnt`.  If only one argument is given, it'll try to find out what the other one _should_ be fromt the `fstab` or `mtab` files.

Comment: i did sudo mount -o remount /dev/sda6 /mnt but it tells me:
mount: you must specify the filesystem type

Comment: @user197060 Sorry about that, forgot something in the command. See the edited step 3

Comment: I tried sudo mount -t ext4 -o remount /dev/sda6 /mnt but i get 
mount: /mnt not mounted or bad option

Comment: @user197060 the command was fixed yet again, confirmed to work now. Thanks for your patience

Comment: i get a long list of information but i can't post it here because too many characters.

Comment: @user at which step? Paste it at http://paste.Ubuntu.com

Comment: (Ok This Is What I Did: sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda6 /mnt (i get) :mkdir: cannot create directory `/opt': File exists)
(Then I Did: sudo cp -Ra /mnt /opt (i get) cp: cannot copy a directory, `/mnt', into itself, `/opt/mnt')

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have /opt on a separate partition.

if you boot partition has sufficient space, try this :

1. Copy your opt partition

   ```
   cp /opt /temp_opt
   ```
2. Start your partition manager and reformat your `/opt` partition. Ensure your your /etc/fstab file is not pointing the partition to mount at /opt.
3. Rename your temporary opt directory

   ```
   mv /temp_opt /opt
   ```